# how do i access properties defined in ItemViewModel class in Mainpage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

i have MedicicineModel (MainViewModel class ) and MedicineData (ItemViewModel class ) . i have three properties defined in MedicineData class as follows :

```
namespace MedicinePlus.ViewModels
{
    public class MedicineData
    {
        public string ProblemName { get; set; }
        public string ProblemDesc { get; set; }
        public string ProblemImageFilePath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MedicineModel class is as follows :

```
namespace MedicinePlus.ViewModels
{
public class MedicineModel
{
    public List<MedicineData> Problems { get; set; }
    public MedicineModel()
    {
        this.Problems = new List<MedicineData>();
    }

    public bool IsDataLoaded { get; set; }

    public void LoadData()
    {
    //place design time datat here
        IsDataLoaded = true;
        this.Problems.Add(new MedicineData() { ID = 0, ProblemName = "Fever",  ProblemDesc = "rise in body temperature", ProblemImageFilePath = "/Assets/Images/fever.png" });
        this.Problems.Add(new MedicineData() { ID = 2, ProblemName = "sprain", ProblemDesc = "Caused due to muscle pull", ProblemImageFilePath = "/Assets/Images/sprain1.png" });
        this.Problems.Add(new MedicineData() { ID = 3, ProblemName = "bruise", ProblemDesc = "irritation in the concerned area", ProblemImageFilePath = "/Assets/Images/headache.png" });

    }

}
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs is as follows :

```
namespace MedicinePlus
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }
private void submitMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

QUERY : now i want to access ProblemName , ProblemDesc and ProblemImgPath in code block of submit_Click event handler . how do i do it

Comment: buddy learn databinding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does your ViewModel is binded with View. or you just access those without binding?

Comment: The last missing piece to solve the problem, post your XAML so we can see where you put `submitMenu_Click` event handler

Comment: The quick unhelpful answer is *don't*. You're separating your data from your view for a reason, so stick to that and instead handle your click in a viewmodel not in the view. Use the `ICommand` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really supplied enough information for us to answer definitively, so all we can do is to guess. For example, what object is in the `App.ViewModel` property? Is it a `MedicineModel` instance? If it is, then you seem to have overlooked that property. Surely you can access your view model and its data using it?:

```
private void submitMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MedicineModel viewModel = App.ViewModel;
    List<MedicineData> problems = viewModel.Problems;
    string problemName = problems[0].ProblemName;
}
```

If this is not what you're after, then perhaps you'd be good enough to actually tell us in more detail exactly what your want and what problems you are having.

Comment: yes , app.viewmodel contains instance of MeicineModel class . then cant i access it like this : string problemName = App.ViewModel.Problems[0].ProblemName;

Comment: Yes, but really, you should check that the collection contains any items first: `if (problems.Count > 1) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of `MedicineData`,

```
MedicineData medicineData = new medicineData();
```

and then you can access them as simple as:

```
medicineData.ProblemName
medicineData.ProblemDesc
```

and

```
medicineData.ProblemImageFilePath
```